# CIFS VFS: \\storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net Send error in SessSetup = -13, STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

Tags: azure, ubuntu, mount, azure-storage-account, fstab

We have a storage account in azure in which we have a file share that we're mounting on our Ubuntu machine on `/path/to/mountdirectroy/`
it was working fine until I checked today and found that it is no longer mounted

`df -h` shows

```
df: /path/to/mountdirectroy/: Host is down
```

checking the dmesg error (kernel error)

```
 CIFS VFS: \\storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net Send error in SessSetup = -13
 Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
 CIFS VFS: \\storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net Send error in SessSetup = -13
```

the `/etc/fstab` file looks like this

```
//storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/fileshare_name /path/to/mountdirectroy/ cifs nofail,vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/mycredentails.cred,uid=mysql,gid=mysql,dir_mode=0750,file_mode=0750,serverino
```

where `mycredentails.cred` looks like

```
username=storageaccount_name
password=storageaccount_key
```

I already checked the key and the username, they are correct

any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finaly fixed the issue by just unmounting the share by `umount  /path/to/mountdirectroy/` and mount all shares again by `mount -a`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `domain = yourdomain`.

Comment: Hi Haitam, I suggest reading through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask post more details to your questions so that others can understand how to help out